# Iterate through a list in python while skipping values

Tags: python, loops

I have a number list, and I want to iterate through all of them and do following calculations.

Each of those values added to `load demand` and subtract from `available power`. My code iterate to a certain point and stops the calculation.

```
num = [5,2,1,2,8,1,2]

Pa = 130            #available power
Ld = 100            #total load demad
Pn = 0              #new power request
node =0

for number in num:
    Pa -= num[node]
    Ld += num[node]
    if Pa >= Ld:
        Pna = Pa
        Lnd = Ld
        Pn += num[node]

        #print "new added value is : ", Pn
    node += 1

print "Available power : ", Pna
print "Demand power : ", Lnd
```

Output is

```
Available power :  120
Demand power :  110
```

This iterate to 5th element and stops, I want to keep iterate from 6th element while skipping values that `Pa >= Ld` becomes false.

I am new for Python, so my coding structure may not be good. Is there a way to satisfy my requirement using `for` and `if` loops or another method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think it stops iterating? You decrement `Pa` and increment `Ld` at each iteration; since `num` contains only positive numbers, once `Pa >= Ld` is false, the body of that `if` statement will never execute again. Look at the values of `Pa`, `Ld`, and `node` after the loop completes.

Comment: Is this code correctly indented?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to understand. I want to keep iterating while skipping values where `Pa >= Ld` becomes false

Comment: Is your original intention to change `Pa` and `Ld`original values each iteration? or do you want to just change them temporarily while maintaining the original values adding and subtracting to those?

Comment: use the continue statement

Comment: @droravr I want to change `Pa` and `Ld` every iteration.

Comment: may be linked to the fact that you have 5 values only (1 and 2 are both in two occurences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't modify `Pa` or `Ld` until after you verify that the current node value is acceptable.

```
num = [5, 2, 1, 2, 8, 1, 2]

Pa = 130            #available power
Ld = 100            #total load demad
Pn = 0              #new power request

for node in num:
    temp_Pa = Pa - node
    temp_Ld = Ld + node
    if temp_Pa >= temp_Ld:
        Pa = temp_Pa
        Ld = temp_Ld
        Pn += node
        print(node, 'ok', Pn, Pa, Ld)
    else:
        print('skipping', node)

print("Available power : ", Pa)
print("Demand power : ", Ld)
```

**output**

```
5 ok 5 125 105
2 ok 7 123 107
1 ok 8 122 108
2 ok 10 120 110
skipping 8
1 ok 11 119 111
2 ok 13 117 113
Available power :  117
Demand power :  113
```

Comment: This worked for me and satisfied my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: You can ditch temps and just use - `if Pa-node >= Ld+node`

Comment: @droravr We _could_ do that, but then we need to recompute those values if the condition is True. `Pa-node` creates an integer object, binding that object to a name for later use is cheaper than re-doing the arithmetic. It's not a big deal, but I prefer to make my code more efficient unless doing so makes it overly cluttered. And of course in situations where we _need_ to optimize it, a little clutter is tolerable. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your iterations don't stop, only your condition in the `if` statement becomes `False`.

In spite of this, you may replace this part of your code

```
node =0

for number in num:
    Pa -= num[node]
    Ld += num[node]
    if Pa >= Ld:
        Pna = Pa
        Lnd = Ld
        Pn += num[node]

        #print "new added value is : ", Pn
    node += 1
```

with this

```
for node, number in enumerate(num):
    Pa -= num[node]
    Ld += num[node]
    if Pa >= Ld:
        Pna = Pa
        Lnd = Ld
        Pn += num[node]

        #print "new added value is : ", Pn
```

to not manually increase the `node` index. The `enumerate()` function will do it for you.

The better solution is however

```
for number in num:
    Pa -= number
    Ld += number
    if Pa >= Ld:
        Pna = Pa
        Lnd = Ld
        Pn += number

        #print "new added value is : ", Pn
```

Python is not C language, you don't need use the index for accessing items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Put a trace `print` statement in your loop like this:

```
Pa -= num[node]
Ld += num[node]
print "Node",node, "Pa=", Pa, "Ld=",Ld
```

At the 5th iteration it prints

```
Node 4 Pa= 112 Ld= 118
Node 5 Pa= 111 Ld= 119
Node 6 Pa= 109 Ld= 121
```

At Node 4 the test `Pa >= Ld` is `False`. As you can see from the trace, although your code changes these values, it doesn't change them enough to affect the `if`-test, and so the code inside the `if` won't execute for the rest of the iteration.